# how i set loading on save button extjs4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Hi i have save button and submit form, when i click show loading icon when form are not submitted. Please help me, in extjs 4.

```
buttons:[{ 
   text: save,
   handler: function(){ 
      form.submit({ 
          /sucess or failure code here; 
      }) 
   }
}]
```

Comment: Please re-form your question. It's not clear what exactly are you asking for.

Answer (score 1):

- First you need a gif file for "waiting icon" with appropriate size.
- Then you create a css class for your "Save" button in waiting status. For example:

```
.save-waiting {
    background-image: url("url-to-your-waiting-gif-file");
}
```

- Finally toggle the Save button to include this class when submitting form with:

```
    saveButton.addCls('save-waiting');
    // may disable the save button here
```

After successful response of submission, you remove the "waiting status" on the button or something else

```
saveButton.removeCls('save-waiting');
```